# Cross-Origin Request - "Same origin" blocked on GET request

Tags: rest, vue.js, heroku, sails.js, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to deploy a SAILS app & a VUE app on heroku with a custom domain. I'm currently facing with something that seems to be a CORS issue, but I do not understand this one.

**Problem**

When I send a GET request to my backend in stage mode, (with postman or my frontend-app) I get an error message :

> "... blocking Cross-Origin Request : the "same origin" policy does not
>   allow access to the resource located at
>   https://*app-frontend*.herokuapp.com/api/v1/account/user-controller
>   ...".

The HTML response is :

```
Status 503 →Service Unavailable
Cache-Control →no-cache, no-store
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →511
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 24 Jul 2018 08:17:13 GMT
Server →Cowboy
```

And my sails console gives me this info :

`Redirecting GET request from 'undefined.' subdomain...`

But with POST requests, I don't face to this problem and my route is well defined as it works in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting `csrf: false` in the `config/security.js`? It shouldn't affect GET requests, but the key to your problem might be somewhere there.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already had set `csrf: false` in my config folder. My problems has evolved. I've added some allowed headers, and now i have to handle with a **302** error. Which is better I think.

In my HTTP response, I receive this header : `location 
https://p003-frontend-staging.…api/v1/account/user-controller` -> Seems that my issue stands here -> this refer to a route I have never set. Do I have to parameter manually this **Location** header to a right route in my server response. Why my server choose to send the response to this URL exactly ?

Comment: @qvdp we actually talked yesterday in the sails chatroom, I believe. I have no damn clue how this whole thing works and I already ditched it in favor of Meteor+React combo. Sails was failing too much on me.